# Optimized solution for a rolling dice code puzzle

Tags: php, array, interview-questions, php5, dice

I was asked to provide the solution of this rolling dice problem in an interview. When I showed him my solution, he said that there is another way to find the solution. I am looking for answer in PHP script only.

> Question:
>
> Two persons are playing a game of rolling 2 dices. Each person rolls the two dices n times and records the outcomes (sum of value of two dices) of all the n attempts. So after n attempts of both the player we have two list corresponding to the n outcomes of two players.
>
> They want to know that whether they have got all possible outcomes( 1 to 12) same number of times or not. If they got all the possible outcomes same number of times then they are called lucky otherwise unlucky.
>
> **Input**: Two Integer Arrays (L1, L2) corresponding to outcomes of two players.
>
> **Output**: Lucky or Unlucky depending on the case

My Answer:

```
<?php
function rollingdice($input1,$input2)
{
  foreach($input1 as $k=>$a)
  { 
    if(in_array($a,$input2))
    {$p = array_search($a, $input2);
     unset($input2[$p]);
    }
    else
    { return 'Unlucky';}
  }
return 'Lucky';
}
?>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just compare the two arrays directly? Ideally after sorting.

Comment: _all possible outcomes (1 to 12)_ You can't roll a 1 with two dice. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your use of `in_array()`, you don't appear to be concerned with the order of the elements. In that case, you can simply sort the arrays and compare them directly.

```
function compare($array1, $array2)
{
    sort($array1);
    sort($array2);

    return ($array1 == $array2) ? "Lucky" : "Unlucky";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With extra `O(n)` space the complexity can be made `O(n)` only, without sorting that will take `O(nlogn)`

Use a map and add a value for each key as (previousValue +1) or (previousValue - 1) based on array type A or B.
Also use a counter to track an absolute increase or decrease if at end the counter is 0. Then the two array has same number of occurrence else not.

[Edited: Added code]

A java implementation

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> trackMap = new HashMap<>();
        int n = 6;
        int[] a = {4, 12, 4, 10, 6, 10};
        int[] b = {10, 12, 10, 4, 4, 6};
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (!trackMap.containsKey(a[i])) {
                trackMap.put(a[i], 1);
                counter++;
            } else {
                int prevVal = trackMap.get(a[i]);
                trackMap.put(a[i], prevVal + 1);
                counter = counter + ((Math.abs(prevVal) > Math.abs(prevVal + 1)) ? -1 : 1);
            }
            if (!trackMap.containsKey(b[i])) {
                trackMap.put(b[i], -1);
                counter++;
            } else {
                int prevVal2 = trackMap.get(b[i]);
                trackMap.put(b[i], prevVal2 - 1);
                counter = counter + ((Math.abs(prevVal2) > Math.abs(prevVal2 - 1)) ? -1 : 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter == 0 ? "Lucky" : "Unlucky");
    }
}
```

Or instead if using counter, you cand finally iterate the hashMap if all value are zero then the person is lucky else not

Comment: Would you mind demonstrating this technique so that I can be sure I understand your theory?

Comment: @mickmackusa sure. 
Also looking if can be done using better complexity in term of space.

Comment: I only code in php.  I thought this was a php question.

Answer (score 2):

@Mr AJ already gave you a valid answer on the algorithmic approach in his Java example, but since it seems Java is unfamiliar to you, I will just write out the algorithm here in a way that hopefully makes sense to you.

There is no need to sort the arrays, doing so ensure more operational complexity than is needed here, as now your a guaranteeing that you are visiting each value in the arrays at least twice (once for sorting, once for reading out sorted values - yes this even happens under the hood in with a `==` comparison between two sorted arrays as happens in currently selected answer).  You can achieve the goal by iterating each array a single time, such that you only visit each value once.

Your logic should be along the lines of:

- Compare array sizes, if unequal then 'Unlucky'.
- Iterate over first array, building a map (perhaps an associative array or `stdClass` object in PHP).  Keys are values encountered in the array (i.e. 2-12) and the values for this map are the counts of each of the corresponding dice values.  You should probably also error on condition of getting value outside the 2-12 range in the array.
- Iterate over the second array, if a dice value is encountered that is not present as a key in the map built from first array, then 'Unlucky'.  Otherwise you decrement the stored count in the map by one each time a corresponding dice value is encountered.
- Iterate over the map values, if any value is not equal to 0 then 'Unlucky' else 'Lucky'.

This provides an `O(2n)` worst-case operational complexity, where `n` is the size of the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the other answers that speak in depth on the theory and big O, I thought I would script up my interpretation.

Code: ([Demo with echoed variables to show values and processes](https://3v4l.org/FiXKa))

```
function roll() {
    return rand(1, 6) + rand(1, 6);
}

$roller1 = [];
$roller2 = [];
$totalRolls = 1;

for ($i = 0; $i < $totalRolls; ++$i) {
    $roller1[] = roll();
    $roller2[] = roll();
}

$map = array_count_values($roller1);
    
$outcome = 'Lucky';
foreach ($roller2 as $roll) {
    if (!empty($map[$roll])) {
        --$map[$roll];
    } else {
        $outcome = 'Unlucky';
        break;
    }
}

echo $outcome;
```

After the formation of the two arrays, php offers a simple function call to create the map of roll values and the number of instances of each value -- `array_count_values()`.  This action is only necessary on the first array.

The second array is then iterated and each value is checked against the map.  If the given value is not a key in the map or it is has a falsey (`0`) value at the key, then there is a mismatch between `$roller1` and `$roller2` -- the outcome is `Unlucky` and the loop is sensibly broken/halted.  As matches are found between the map and the second array, the encountered map keys have their respective value decremented (spent) to enable the correct action with `empty()`.

As @MikeBrant said:

> This provides an `O(2n)` worst-case operational complexity, where n is the size of the arrays.

the worse-case scenario is the only way to achieve the `Lucky` outcome.

A best-case operational complexity (`Unlucky` outcome) where the map is generated (`n`) and the loop breaks on the first element in the second array (`1`) ...`o(n+1)`.

As for speed, I don't know.  I didn't benchmark this script against the double-sort&compare technique, but you will notice that my technique is calling `array_count_values()` and will make iterated `empty()` calls and every function call equates to some level of a performance hit (even if miniscule).